# MVC Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and I'm currently working on a project with an existing database and a web API controller. What is mean't by projecting the data from the Entity Framework instances?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the context. You should provide more info. It might mean that you need to generate the C# models for the Db context, using entity framework. It might mean that you need to use DB-first instead of Code-first....

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-2) and see if it answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Projecting the data from the Entity Framework instances means to use your DbContext class to fetch data from db or to save data to db.
If you are working with the EF Designer, the context will be generated for you.
If you are working with Code First Approach, then u have to generate code context manually.

```
    public class ProductContext : DbContext 
    { 
     public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } 
     public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
     }
```

Once you have a context, you would query for, add (using Add or Attach methods ) or remove (using Remove) entities in the context through these properties. Accessing a DbSet property on a context object represent a starting query that returns all entities of the specified type. Note that just accessing a property will not execute the query. A query is executed when:

It is enumerated by a foreach.
It is enumerated by a collection operation such as ToArray, ToDictionary, or ToList.
LINQ operators such as First or Any are specified in the outermost part of the query.
The following methods are called: the Load extension method on a DbSet, DbEntityEntry.Reload, and Database.ExecuteSqlCommand.

you should refer this website to grasp the things more deeply.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/entity-framework5-introduction.aspx